# How to remove an account?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts, uac

The title isn't too informative, but I couldn't think of a more accurate one.

Long back, I had a problem in logging to my account (Admin). It showed

> The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.

I quickly looked around the net and decided to copy my files through another account.

That is, I copied the entire sub-folders of `C:\Users\Amit Joki\` and pasted them into `C:\Users\Amit`.

So, I created another account named "Amit"(the previous one was "Amit Joki") which I connected through Microsoft(in Windows 8.1), as it prompted me to do so, and made it the "Administrator"

My previous account too was connected with the same email, if that helps.

Now, I noticed something odd. Whenever I tried to upload a pic to some websites, it alerted something along the lines(I'm not sure)

> The path C:\Users\Amit Joki\Pictures no longer exists

And that happens only the first time, and even then the alert just comes and goes. I'm left to stare my "Pictures" folder. Subsequent times, it doesn't alert that message. Obviously, it was looking for the path in "Amit Joki" user, though I was logged in with "Amit"

Also, what's more interesting is some of my apps like `Visual Studio Ultimate 2013` has `(2)` attached to its name.

Like `Visual Studio 2013 (2)`, some other programs with such names are

```
Windows PowerShell (2)

RegExr (2) // its a third party app which I had downloaded when using "Amit Joki" user.
```

Also, I'm not able to delete `C:\Users\Amit Joki`. The folder just remains there. How can I solve this issue?

I suppose two accounts are getting mixed up. How can I clear up the mess, I created?

Comment: At first glance, it seems you copied configuration/settings files that should not have been copied over. Please give more details about this step you took: **"I quickly looked around the net and decided to copy my files through another account."**. Which files did you copy - from where to where?

Comment: @Tyler I've edited to make that clear.

Comment: @Tyler I've just copied whatever was inside the old profile's user folder to the new account's user folder.

Comment: If you can log back in to the Amit Joki account, delete your Amit account and start over. Use Windows Easy Transfer to copy over the files you need. It will work between accounts on the same computer. Some good tips here to look through as well: http://superuser.com/a/625110/387876